# Java - associate an attribute with a logical preposition

Tags: java, predicate

I have a series of attributes that either are, or are not, applied to my object:

```
EVEN
ODD
POSITIVE
NEGATIVE
NEGATIVE_AND_ODD
```

and each of them applies to the object iff some logical statement holds true, i.e.

```
EVEN iff num%2==0
ODD iff num%2!=0
POSITIVE iff num>0
NEGATIVE iff num<0
NEGATIVE_AND_ODD iff num < 0 and num%2==0
```

I have a large number of these attributes and new attributes can be added at any time. Attributes have no dependency on each other nor should they ever create such a dependency.

I need a scheme so that my main class can do something like:

```
Go through the list of attributes
  If this attribute fits its required logical predicate, then 
    add the attribute to my object
```

What kind of tools would you use for this?

Comment: What does `new attributes can be added at any time.` mean? Can they be added while the program is running? How are the predicates defined?

Comment: "New attributes can be added at any time" only means that I shouldn't expect this list to remain static. They will be added normally to the program. The predicates are defined by business logic and there's no real "pretty" connection between the predicates and the attributes.

Comment: But how are the predicated expressed? Are they exactly as `iff num%2==0`, i.e. in some language that you will need to parse and evaluate the predicate?

Comment: @MiserableVariable They are basically simple boolean statements, yeah. In some cases it is as simple as "if someBoolean". In other cases it is "if someBoolean and someNumber = 3"

Comment: `if someBoolean and someNumber = 3` are not very simple. I assume `someBoolean` and `someNumber` are properties of your object? Tou would still need to parse and bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this

```
 interface Attribute
 {
      public boolean matches(boolean someBoolean, int num);
 }
```

and then implementing each attribute like

```
 class Even implements Attribute
 {
     public boolean matches(boolean someBoolean, int num)
     {
         // someBoolean is not important to this attribute
         // but it may be in others
         return num%2==0;
     }
 }
```

Then you could just make an array (or list or whatever) of `Attribute`, and loop through them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

- Create an interface `Attribute` with a single method `boolean check(int num);`
- Create a class for each attribute, implementing the check() method to perform the check for each attribute. You could use anonymous inner classes for this if you want to save typing.
- Create a List with one instance of each attribute

Then you can implement your algorithm pretty much directly: just loop over the attributes and call check on the appropriate value for each one.

Answer (score 1):

A [Predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29) is a boolean value function that given an input tests whether an attribute is true or false. Predicates are also called properties which are synonyms of attributes.

I would start by defining a `Predicate` interface.

```
public abstract class Predicate<T> {
    public abstract boolean eval(T t);
    public Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> p) {...};
    public Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> ... p) {...};
    public Predicate<T> negate() {...};
    public Predicate<T> or(Predicate<? super T> p) {...};
    public Predicate<T> or(Predicate<? super T> ... p) {...};
    public Predicate<T> xor(Predicate<? super T> p) {...};
    public Predicate<T> xor(Predicate<? super T> ... p) {...};
}
```

Then you can define each of your attributes:

```
public static final Predicate<Integer> EVEN = new Predicate<Integer>(){
    public boolean eval(Integer n) {
        return n % 2 == 0;
    }
};
```

Assuming that you want to filter a set of integers based on their properties, then I will assume you will have to define a filtering method (which corresponds to a classical [high-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) to filter items on a given predicate):

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(List<? extends T> items, 
                                 Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T item : items){
        if(predicate.eval(item)){
            result.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Let's see an example of this filtering in action:

```
List<Integer> myNumbers = asList(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> onlyEven = filter(myNumbers, EVEN);
List<Integer> positiveAndEven = filter(myNumbers, POSITIVE.and(EVEN));
```

The good about this approach is that once [JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/) is released all this functionality will be provided by the language through the use of [lambda expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html).

Ultimately, you will replace your attribute definitions for lambda expressions:

```
public static final Predicate<Integer> EVEN = n -> n % 2 == 0;
public static final Predicate<Integer> ODD = n -> n % 2 != 0;
public static final Predicate<Integer> POSITIVE = n -> n > 0;
public static final Predicate<Integer> NEGATIVE = n -> n < 0;
```

And you filtering will be provided built-in in your collections, so you would simply do:

```
List<Integer> myNumbers = asList(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> onlyEven = myNumbers.filter(EVEN).into(new ArrayList<Integer>());
List<Integer> positiveEven = myNumbers.filter(POSITIVE.and(EVEN)).into(new ArrayList<Integer>());
List<Integer> positiveOrOdd = myNumbers.filter(POSITIVE.or(ODD)).into(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

The predicate interface will be part of JDK 8 `java.util.functions` package. So, ultimately you will be able to to throw away yours and use the one built into the JDK.